# Add annotation to axis text for ggcorrplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I am using `ggcorrplot` to plot the correlation matrix of large datasets. The problem is that it's difficult to see the labels of the axis text (in the example below it would be e.g., `sample1`). Associated to each label, I have another label (in the example below it would be e.g., `normal` for `sample1`). Is it possible to annotate the axis text labels with a parenthesis or a box around each level of the samples' labels?

```
cor.vals <- cor(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10))
colnames(cor.vals) <- paste0("sample", 1:10)
rownames(cor.vals) <- colnames(cor.vals)
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(cor.vals)
labels.samples <- c(rep("normal", 5), rep("drug", 5))
```

[image]

Similarly for the x-axis. My data are much larger with many more categories, so adding them manually is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact look you are going for is not achievable directly within `ggplot`. You can do it by adding shapes manually using `grid`, but I note that you feel this is not really an option.

One logically equivalent and similar look could be achieved with facets, though that requires fiddling with the output of `ggcorrplot`:

```r
p <- ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(cor.vals)

p$data$facets_y <- factor(rep(labels.samples, length = nrow(p$data)), c("normal", "drug"))
p$data$facets_x <- rep(labels.samples, each = length(labels.samples))
p$coordinates <- coord_cartesian()

p + facet_grid(facets_x~facets_y, scales = "free", switch = "both") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(-0.02, "npc"),
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(color = c("black")))
```

[image]